# effective c# second edition errata

Tags: c#, errata

I am making the move from java to c#. I am reading Bill Wagner's book, Effective C# second edition. I am currently at item 6 "Understand the relationships among the many different concepts of equality" in chapter 1 where there's a sample code in pages 40-41-42 that is supposed to show how incorrectly implementing Equals can lead to errors, errors that i am unable to reproduce, it looks like an error in the sample. here's the code below

```
public class B : IEquatable<D>
{
    public override bool Equals(object right)
    {
        //
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(right, null))
            return false;
        // Check reference equality:
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(this, right))
            return true;
        // Problems here, discussed below.
        B rightAsB = right as B;
        if (rightAsB == null)
            return false;
        return this.Equals(rightAsB);
    }

    #region IEquatable<B> Members
    public bool Equals(B other)
    {
        // elided
        return true;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

and class D inheriting from B

```
public class D : B,IEquatable<D>
{
    // etc.
    public override bool Equals(object right)
    {
        // check null:
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(right, null))
            return false;
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(this, right))
            return true;
        // Problems here.
        D rightAsD = right as D;

        if (rightAsD == null)
            return false;
        if (base.Equals(rightAsD) == false)
            return false;
        return this.Equals(rightAsD);
    }

    #region IEquatable<D> Members
    public bool Equals(D other)
    {
        // elided.
        return true; // or false, based on test
    }
    #endregion
}
```

according to the book, the following code

```
        B baseObject = new B();
        D derivedObject = new D();
        // Comparison 1.
        if (baseObject.Equals(derivedObject))
            Console.WriteLine("Equals");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Not Equal");
        // Comparison 2.
        if (derivedObject.Equals(baseObject))
            Console.WriteLine("Equals");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Not Equal");
```

"the second comparison will never return true", well it does. I mean since D is a subclass of B, the second comparison will end up calling the Equals method from B which returns true and that makes total sense to me. am i missing something?

Comment: Your code sample as posted does not compile.

Comment: i am sorry you are right, the error is in the definition of class B, it should implement interface IEquatable<B> and not IEquatable<D>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect Bill meant that if the *overridden* `Equals(object)` method in `D` is called with `baseObject`, it will return false, due to this part:

```
D rightAsD = right as D;

if (rightAsD == null)
    return false;
```

Given that the value of `baseObject` is *not* a reference to an instance of `D`, `rightAsD` should be `null`, so it'll return `false`.

To demonstrate this, just change the types of the `baseObject` and `derivedObject` *variables* to `object`. (Don't change the values they're initialized to, just the declared type.) Alternatively, just cast to `object`:

```
if (derivedObject.Equals((object) baseObject))
```

So the book is right in saying that the implementation has a problem - it's just that the sample doesn't quite demonstrate it.

Comment: straight to the point! thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the `as` operator and inheritance.

Suppose you have 2 classes, `A` and `B`, and `B` derives from `A`.

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();

A x = b as A; // x is b
B y = a as B; // y is null
```

Comment: But `derivedObject.Equals(baseObject)` will call `B.Equals(B)` - which returns true. That's the problem.

Comment: It should call `B`'s `public override bool Equals(object right)`, no not the more specific one?  Which would result in failure on the `as` statement?

Comment: Do you mean to demonstrate the problem? Yes.

Comment: Yes, I was just trying to explain how it failed.